# SVG to JPEG conversion using Apache Batik 1.8

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am trying to convert an `SVG` to `JPEG` using `Apache Batik 1.8`. It seems that the `batik-codec.jar` version 1.8 is missing all the `JPEG` related classes (they were present in 1.7). Is there any known workaround (other than downgrading to 1.7)?

Comment: There's this which includes a fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1007

Comment: Is there a plan for this bug to be fixed? And will a fix be pushed to a maven repo?

Comment: The patch I submitted for a different issue never landed despite reaching out to the developers and/or asking them for access rights to push to the Batik repo so it seems the Batik project isn't very active currently and getting access rights is quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

SVG to JPEG conversion works with `batik-codec.jar` 1.10 version. So you can upgrade to 1.10 version now.

Note: `batik-transcoder.jar` & `batik-codec.jar` both jars are required to do file conversions (SVG -> JPG/PNG/TIFF).